# How can I connect my dll with a conf file if they are in the same path

Tags: c#, xml

I have a program that needs a XML conf file with a few variants. When I compile the program in C# (Visual Studio 2019), it give me a DLL file. That Dll is going to be for example to

> 'C:\Program Files x86\example\example.dll'

In same path I have my conf file

> 'C:\Program Files x86\example\conf.xml'

I only work with the Dll and the conf file.

**I DON'T USE MY PROYECT ONLY DLL**

So, how can my dll get from the conf file some information from it?

What I need is both files are in the same folder but the XML doesn´t work there. So I need to put something in my Dll to -> if I change of folder my Dll , I will change xml file to the same folder. So what I need it´s to put in my program that anypath were the Dll file is, get that path and read the xml file. Because both files will be in the same path.

Comment: Open the csproj file with notepad.  You should be able to figure out what need to change to solve issue.

Comment: I paste the code?

Comment: Where I change the path os my xml? https://justpaste.it/8jxa6